# why is accessing individual elements of ByteBuffer slower than ByteArray with an extra copy?

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, jvm

this a part of a camerax analyser for rotating the image:
the y buffer is passed to the set method and individual bytes are read through the get method or the [] operator

```
private data class IImage(var byteArray: ByteArray= ByteArray(0), var width: Int=0, var height: Int=0)
{
    //set rotationDegrees to 0 to disable rotation
    fun Set(rotationDegrees:Int,buffer:ByteBuffer,w:Int,h:Int){
        if (byteArray.size != buffer.capacity()) byteArray =ByteArray(buffer.capacity()) //resize buffer
        if(rotationDegrees == 0 || rotationDegrees % 90 != 0){ buffer.get(byteArray); width=w; height=h}
        else
        {
            for (y in 0 until h) // we scan the array by rows
                for (x in 0 until w)
                    when (rotationDegrees) {
                        90 -> byteArray[x * h + h - y - 1] = buffer.get(x + y * w) // Fill from top-right toward left (CW)
                        180 -> byteArray[w * (h - y - 1) + w - x - 1] = buffer.get(x + y * w) // Fill from bottom-right toward up (CW)
                        270 -> byteArray[y + x * h] = buffer.get(y * w + w - x - 1) // The opposite (CCW) of 90 degrees
                    }
            if (rotationDegrees != 180) { height = w; width = h }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the same code but using an extra ByteArray

```
 private data class IImage2(var byteArray: ByteArray= ByteArray(0), var width: Int=0, var height: Int=0)
{
    //set rotationDegrees to 0 to disable rotation
    fun Set(rotationDegrees:Int,buffer:ByteBuffer,w:Int,h:Int){
        if (byteArray.size != buffer.capacity()) byteArray =ByteArray(buffer.capacity()) //resize buffer
        buffer.get(byteArray); width=w; height=h
        if(rotationDegrees == 0 || rotationDegrees % 90 != 0) return
        else
        {
            val tByteArray=ByteArray(byteArray.size)
            for (y in 0 until h) // we scan the array by rows
                for (x in 0 until w)
                    when (rotationDegrees) {
                        90 -> tByteArray[x * h + h - y - 1] = byteArray[x + y * w] // Fill from top-right toward left (CW)
                        180 -> tByteArray[w * (h - y - 1) + w - x - 1] = byteArray[x + y * w] // Fill from bottom-right toward up (CW)
                        270 -> tByteArray[y + x * h] = byteArray[y * w + w - x - 1] // The opposite (CCW) of 90 degrees
                    }
            byteArray=tByteArray
            if (rotationDegrees != 180) { height = w; width = h }
        }
    }
}
```

the analysis class stores a single instance of the IImage or IImage2, the IImage code results in 5:7 fps while the IImage results in 9/10:12 fps consistently on the emulator, why is making another ByteArray and copying the data 2 times faster than accessing individual bytes of the ByteBuffer

Comment: You need to look up affine transforms. They are a much quicker ways of doing this than with a switch statement.

Comment: @user207421 I agree that the OP should use the tools for affine transforms instead of reinventing the wheel. But the builtin facilities also have special treatment for multiples of 90° for good reasons (avoid rounding errors and better performance)…

Comment: @Holger I was suggesting he look up the right mathematical way to do it. I got bitten by this 20 years ago when a colleague in charge of the graphics did it all from scratch without any basis knowledge at all. He perpetrated several major blunders that are still with the system 23 years later.

Comment: @user207421,@Holger, most likely I'm misunderstanding something since I don't know o f any builtins for this, I'm using the zxing's barcode reader, so I only need to pass the yplane as a buffer, wouldn't rotating it by a loop & when be faster than converting the image to a bitmap, use an affine transform then transform it back & extract the yBuffer to a byte array? or is there a shorter path that I'm missing?